# Most effective way to split a sorted array around a key

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, split

Consider I have an array of sorted numbers from 1 to 10.
I want to split the array based on a key element.
For say:

```
   Key  Transformed Array
    1   [2-10]
    5   [2-4],[6-10]
    6   [2-4],[7-10]
    7   [2-4],[8-10]
    8   [2-4],[9-10]
    10  [2-4],[9-9]
```

I dont intend to do iteratively if the keys are consecutive,
Meaning,

```
Keys 5,6,7 and 8 have to be processed in one step breaking 
[2-4],[6-10] into [2-4],[9-10]
```

Comment: You problem statement is not clear. Also, What you have tried so far?, Please post that also.

Comment: To be more specific, I have a range of consecutive numbers in a list(A).
I also have a list(B) of numbers to be deleted from the list. Deleting a number thats in between the list(A) should cause the list(A) to be split into two smaller lists and deleting a number thats in the beginning or ending of the list should shrink the list. I have these numbers in the database, and I plan to do this calculation in the Java layer as its intensive to do it with SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use the [Collectors.partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) method along with Java 8's [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Partition {

    public static String join(int[] a, String d) {
        return Arrays.stream(a).mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(d));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int k = 4;
        Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> partitions = Arrays.stream(v)
            .boxed()
            .filter(n -> n != k)
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(n -> n < k));

        int[] vlt = partitions.get(true).stream()
                              .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
        int[] vgt = partitions.get(false).stream()
                              .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

        System.out.println("vlt: {" + join(vlt, ", ") + "}");
        System.out.println("vgt: {" + join(vgt, ", ") + "}");
    }

}
```

On a side note, personally I would just use `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]` and skip the conversion if that's an option.

Comment: I will try this out

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.